# Postgres SQL select into encrypted csv

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Postgres AWS RDS instance and want to export some stuff in encrypted csv file. I don't want to first export and then to encrypt because I will have a moment when the files are unencrypted at rest.

Is there a SELECT statement that can include encrypt action.

My SQL statement now is:

```
copy (select * from TABLE) to '/tmp/DAILY.csv' with csv header
```

Comment: `copy ... TO PROGRAM  xxx yyy`

Comment: What would be that PROGRAM?

Comment: a program that reads from stdin , encrypts, and writes to a file(or stdout)

Comment: I see. OK thank you very much.